# Sending custom HTTP headers with an SSRS Rendering Extension

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

There is a known problem with SSRS Rendering, which is that when rendering PDFs a `Content-Disposition: attachment; ...` header is sent which forces the file to download rather than open inline ([here's an SO thread about it from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584609/how-to-display-a-reporting-services-report-as-an-inline-pdf-in-a-asp-net-and-c)).

I am wondering if this can be worked around to make the PDF open in the browser by using a [Rendering Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/rendering-extension/rendering-extensions-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) in SSRS. I found an example Rendering Extension in C#, here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/johannh/2017/07/14/creating-and-debugging-a-ssrs-custom-rendering-extension/

However, that code appears to only output a stream. Is it possible to somehow send headers before the stream is sent and therefore override the `Content-Disposition` header that is usually sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received a response to a Microsoft ticket from one of the SSRS engineers at Microsoft, who confirmed that SSRS itself sends the `Content-Disposition` header because it is not intended to be used to serve data, and therefore the Rendering Extensions cannot change the header.

**The proposed solutions suggested by the SSRS engineer were:**

- Use a custom application to strip the header post-rendering and serve the PDF for the user
- Direct the user to the static PDF after it is generated