# Generate HTML To PDF Control for the .NET application

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, winnovative

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generation PDF from HTML (component for .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598980/generation-pdf-from-html-component-for-net)

Has anyone used any open source or paid .NET Control which does the conversion job from html to pdf file? At the moment, i am using Winnovative convertor control. But it has a performance limitation during the generation of bulk pages (like more than 1000) in the pdf. The limitation comes when we use bigger images in the html content. From last 4 months i've been working on the winnovative control and found plenty of major bugs in it. For a small application and usage. winnovative is good but not for the level where application will be used by thousands of clients.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598980/generation-pdf-from-html-component-for-net).

Comment: I read this post, did not help me find the good control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last my company has decided to use pdfReactor from [www.realobjects.com](http://www.realobjects.com). It is much faster and better as compared to winnovative pdf control.

Answer (score 3):

We currently use ABCpdf in one of our more complex applications.  It has served us well and is not very expensive at all.  I like that fact that I can send it raw HTML text and it will render it to a PDF in memory or as a file so we use to generate PDFs on the fly and serve them up via the web without actually ever saving it disk ever.

We have been using it for about 3 years and early on I had to use their support for a very odd issue that was very specific and the support was very fast and help solved the issue quickly.

You can find more information on their website at:
http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514170/html-document-to-pdf) I recently learned of [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Aside from the completely unpronounceable name, it seems to do a decent job of conversions of single pages, and supports some nifty options for generating bookmarks and a TOC from the headings.

I have no idea how it handles heavy loads...

Answer (score 0):

www.pdfsharp.com

Comment: pdfsharp is not really sharp enough to convert html into pdf.

Comment: Why don't you add an actual hyperlink to the site?? It's so easy and so convenient for others........

Answer (score 0):

Here's link to a code project article discussing a free library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx

There's also activepdf: http://www.activepdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have used two:

- [Alt-Soft's Xml2PDF](http://www.alt-soft.com/Products_xml2pdf.aspx) (which also converts XHTML to PDF)
- ExpertPDF's [Html-to-PDF](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/)

Both worked quite okay, but have their quirks and troubles.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I advise to try [**PDF Duo .NET component**](http://www.duodimension.com/html_pdf_asp.net/component_html_pdf.aspx) with main function to convert HTML to PDF.